# Swift Charts: How to shade a highlighted area in a line chart?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts, rulemark

[image]The code below draws a `RuleMark` at the top and bottom of the area I would like to highlight, however, instead of 2 lines I would like to shade this area grey to show the normal range.  How can I do this?

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct StepCount: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let weekday: Date
        let steps: Int
        
        init(day: String, steps: Int) {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
            
            self.weekday = formatter.date(from: day) ?? Date.distantPast
            self.steps = steps
        }
    }
    
    let currentWeek: [StepCount] = [
        StepCount(day: "20220717", steps: 4200),
        StepCount(day: "20220718", steps: 15000),
        StepCount(day: "20220719", steps: 2800),
        StepCount(day: "20220720", steps: 10800),
        StepCount(day: "20220721", steps: 12370),
        StepCount(day: "20220722", steps: 9500),
        StepCount(day: "20220723", steps: 3700)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart {
                ForEach(currentWeek) {
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Week Day", $0.weekday, unit: .day),
                        y: .value("Step Count", $0.steps)
                    )
                }
                RuleMark(y: .value("Max of Range", 10000))
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                RuleMark(y: .value("Min of Range", 6000))
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 200)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the area should span the entire chart (especially with date values) you can use `RectangeMark` like this:

[image]

```
            Chart {
                RectangleMark(
                    xStart: nil,
                    xEnd: nil,
                    yStart: .value("Step Count", 6000),
                    yEnd: .value("Step Count", 10000)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)

                ForEach(currentWeek) {
                    
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Week Day", $0.weekday, unit: .day),
                        y: .value("Step Count", $0.steps)
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AreaMark` or `RectangleMark`. Here is an example with AreaMark:

[image]

```
            Chart {
                ForEach(currentWeek) {
                    AreaMark(x: .value("Week Day", $0.weekday, unit: .day),
                             yStart: .value("Min of Range", 6000),
                             yEnd: .value("Max of Range", 10000))
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)

                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Week Day", $0.weekday, unit: .day),
                        y: .value("Step Count", $0.steps)
                    )
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks!  is there a way to get either the `AreaMark` or the `RectangleMark` span the entire chart instead of only partially like in your screenshot? 

Comment: yep, See 2nd answer